# Running server in background, while app does something else

Tags: sockets, flask, socket.io, pyqt5, flask-socketio

I'm trying to make a desktop app that acts as the trigger to run a server. The app (the server) will also take in data from clients and saves them in the server's computer.

I already made the server in python with flask and socketio. The clients are also working. So now I was going to make the GUI for the server, so that a non-IT person could run this server.

So what I notice in the runServer function (called when 'Run Server' is clicked') that it did worked and it ran the server. However, I cannot do anything else as the server was running. So I tried testing with print statements.

```
        print('hello')
        self.sio.run(self.app, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8090) #running the server         
        print('hello again')
```

'hello' got printed but 'hello again' didn't

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.sio = SocketIO(self.app)
        self.port = 8090

    def init_ui(self):
        self.runServerButton = QPushButton('Run Server')
        self.runServerButton.clicked.connect(self.runServer)

        self.sayHiButton = QPushButton('Say Hi')
        self.sayHiButton.clicked.connect(self.sayHi)

        self.status = QLabel('Server running\nPlease enter address below to client(s)')
        self.address = QLabel('ipaddress')

        vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        vBox.addWidget(self.runServerButton)
        vBox.addWidget(self.sayHiButton)
        vBox.addWidget(self.status)
        vBox.addWidget(self.address)
        self.status.hide()
        self.address.hide()
        vBox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(vBox)
        self.setWindowTitle('SDS App')

        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 200, 200)
        self.show()

    def runServer(self):
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        self.address.setText(ip)
        self.status.show()
        self.address.show()
        self.runServerButton.setEnabled(False)

        print('hello')
        self.sio.run(self.app, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8090) #running the server         
        print('hello again')

    @sio.on('hey waddup')
    def on_waduup():
        print('i\'m fine bro')
        status.setText("I'm fine bro")

    def sayHi(self):
        print('Hi!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So is there a way to run the server in the background? Or is there a back door solution to this e.g. making an executable that runs two files; the server and the gui (which will have to be another client)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `sio.run()` call is blocking, it starts the web server and does not return. What you need to do to not block your GUI application is to make this call in a background thread, so that your button handler function isn't blocked. It would be something like this:

```
def runServer(self):
    # ...
    print('hello')
    self.sio.start_background_task(self.sio.run, host='0.0.0.0', port=8090)
    print('hello again')
```

Documentation for the `start_background_task()` function: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_socketio.SocketIO.start_background_task.